# 404 Not Found on Zend every link

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server-ce, file-not-found

I am new to zend framwork. I have installed zend server CE on Windows 7.
I am not able to browse to any link such as.. `http://myproject/signup`
while `http://myproject/` works well and displays the homepage.

Please suggest what can be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted!

```
<Directory "E:\Zend\apache2/htdocs/myproject/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This needs to be put in the order they relate in case of multiple dependent zend projects!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your `.htaccess` correctly (using `mod_rewrite`)?

A basic `.htaccess` for ZF looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This file should reside in the `public` directory of your project.